# Why is there too much space between bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot graph using data read from file. The data looks like this.

data.csv

[image]

The bar chart is generated using:

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   import matplotlib
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   file_locn = ''r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\data.csv'''
   df = pd.read_csv(file_locn)
   X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
   Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])

   ax0 = plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
   patterns = [ "\\" , "/" , "-", "x","+" , ".", "*", "o", "O" ]

   bars=plt.bar(X, Y,align='edge', width=0.1,color=colors)
   for i in range(len(Y)):
       bars[i].set_hatch(patterns[i])


   # plt.xticks([])#,fontsize=14)

   ax0.set_ylim(0,7000)
   ax0.set_ylabel('Y Label')

   plt.savefig(test.pdf')
   plt.tight_layout()
```

The problem is, there is too much space between the bars. What should I do to reduce this space between the bars?

Comment: Why are you using `width=0.1`?  The default would be `width=0.8`.  You can set it larger, depending on your preferences.  By the way, the recommended way to write your loop would be `for bar, pattern in zip(bars, patterns): bar.set_hatch(pattern)`.  [avoiding explicit indices](https://www.codementor.io/@philbest/stop-using-indices-woab0mh1t)

Comment: My supervisor told me the width of the bars is too big. You are right, my looping here is not recommended. I was just experimenting because your method of looping didn't show the patterns correctly for some reason.

Comment: I am literally dying trying to satisfy him in how "good" my plots look.

Comment: You might try seaborn instead of standard matplotlib.  Something like `sns.set_style('dark'); sns.barplot(data=df, x='Set', y='Score')`. Seaborn usually has some better looking defaults, but *de gustibus non est disputandum*.